# Why do we keep using CSV?

Tags: productivity, ethics

Why do we keep using CSV?

I recently made a shift to working the health domain and despite the wonderful work in data transfer standards, all data transfer is in **CSV**, both for reporting to external organisations, and for data migrations when implementing new systems.

Unfortunately the use of CSV is the cause of the endless repetition of the same stupid errors, with the same waste of developer time. (bad escaping, failing to handle null fields etc.)

I know we can do better, and anything between JSON and XML (depending on the instance) would be fine. (Most of the time this is data going from one MS SQLserver 2005 to another!)

I feel as if each time I see this happening I am literally watching one developer waste anothers time.

So why do we keep shafting each other? When will we stop?

Comment: If your data is going between SQLServers, using SSIS to handle data transfers, it can handle CSV files beautifully.

Comment: If you're just getting into the health domain and you think CSV is bad... just wait until you run into HL7!

Comment: @Greg LOL, don't frighten him, the surprise is always best :)

Comment: -1 This is an anti-CSV rant against problems not caused by CSV. What exactly do you think would happen if you read and wrote XML without a library? Your problems would be a hundred times worse.

Comment: "So why do we keep shafting each other? When will we stop?" I dunno, where I work we manage to use CSV just fine without anyone getting shafted (indeed - it's the XML stage that's by far more frustrating). Maybe you and your coworkers are doing something wrong?

Comment: @Greg I use HL7UK 2.4 every day. Not a problem. I'm not saying it doesn't cost money, and mistakes aren't made. But the producer and consumer are required to produce specifications of what they are doing. When done right it gets the job done.

Comment: @Jesse Millikan yeah it's a rant. But there is a right time and a wrong time to use csv. Its perfect for simple data - that is what it was intended for.

Comment: All of the discussion so far misses a very real problem with CSV: the delimiter character is likely to appear in the data, and CSV takes a less-than-optimal approach to that issue (putting quotes around the data just pushes the problem downstream). A better approach would be to use pipe-delimited files.

Comment: @Larry Coleman HL7 2.x **IS** pipe delimited. (You *can* choose another delimiter, according to the standard, but I've never seen it)

Comment: @Stephen: so what problems have you had with HL7 and why don't you consider that to be a better alternative?

Comment: @Larry Coleman  It **is** a better alternative, _in that it is well specified_.

Comment: @Stephen: I just read the other question about HL7. So never mind; no interchange format/parser can save you from problems with semantics.

Comment: @Larry Coleman I should add that it is well specified for every implementation. The standard itself is implemented differently each time.

Comment: @Larry Coleman, you are right - but having and keeping to a specification can help.

Comment: @Stephen, I too work in the health care domain and is not exactly a top-notch industry in terms of best practices. A few weeks ago a client (an HMO) sent us data in PDF for us to import :-). CSV are usually sent to us in the incorrect layout no matter how many times we specify the layout to them. We are wasting a lot of time right now changing the layouts or our ETL jobs because of it. I'm telling you, I'm growing tired of it everyday. I hope your luck is way better than mine.

Comment: this keeps happening because so many developers just sit there and moan about how they've become a victim of 'politics' without ever making a serious attempt of improving things.

Comment: @Hans Good point. However, some developers, even senior ones I've met, prefer battles they know they can win. Sometimes you pick your battles. In some organizations, you don't have a chance. So, a choice should be made: code or politics. I tend to choose code :-)

Comment: @Larry - surely users can put pipe characters in their data too? AFAIK, there's no character that users aren't allowed to use. I'd even say the more common problem is more likely to be fixed, so commas and quotes may be better in that respect.

Comment: @Steve314: That users can put pipe characters in their data almost goes without saying. It's nothing a backslash escape can't fix.

Comment: I've certainly wasted hours of my life dealing with badly formatted attempts at CSV, but I've also wasted hours dealing with badly formatted attempts at JSON and XML too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case, it seems that CSV isn't a good fit due to it's lack of hard specification.

For non-trivial data it's not the right choice.

Why / When is CSV a good choice? Probably too many instances to mention, the benefits of simplicity for flat data are obvious.  As long as the data is sanitized / escaped properly there are no problems. Generally speaking though, all these cases would be simple / trivial. Of course, the standard delimiter appearing in the content is often a pain when dealing with CSV.

But if you're doing something more involved than getting a non-technical client to send data from an Excel sheet or some other similar use-case, then CSV is probably insufficient for any serious use.

XML is a far better fit (yes even more so than JSON) since you are able to do detailed standardised schema specification for it. (Not to mention that specs/schemas enjoy the flexibility of multiple implementation styles, XSD, DTD & Relax NG)

For closed loop systems, especially where bandwidth is a concern, JSON can be  a better fit than XML, but the lack of schema specification language(s) often precludes it from enterprise level applications.

Comment: Indeed "As long as the data is sanitized / escaped properly". However way to many programmers seem to be able to get this wrong, writing their own (in pseudo-code `write('"');write(fld1);write('"');` ad nauseum.) Then they miss putting quotes around something. Then they write their own parser....

Comment: Yep, the roll-your-own crew really should start using this *internet* thingy, maybe even learn the meaning of the word ... Library.

Comment: sharing information! re-usable code! stupid new-fangled ideas. Repeating other peoples mistakes was good enough for my great^50 grandfather, and it's good enough for me!

Comment: @Steve314 - /me "makes a face of both horror and amusement."

Comment: But CSV does have a hard [specfication](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). Our problem now is the usual one - Excel doesn't conform to it 100%.

Comment: @gbjbaanb sorry, since this is a 4 year old discussion, it's not made abundantly clear.  But it should be noted that I'm referring to CSVs inability to (nicely) express nested data.  That's not to say it's not possible.  But it is a proper pain in the arse.  Clear specification or not.

Comment: @Slomojo but the OP is about CSV data, not nested data in CSV format. Nested data needs XML or similar, flat data is handled nicely in CSV. Anyway, I just thought your opening sentence needed the update.

Comment: @gbjbaanb probably.   I would usually recommend CSV (with caveats) for a flat table.  My answer is to discourage its use for general cases of data-interchange.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - btw, on re-reading the question and my answer "lack of hard specification" is reference to the OP's problem case, ie. the case lacks hard specs, hence the appearance of nulls and poorly escaped strings.  AFAIK Tooling for CSV schema validation is still fairly rudimentary.  So it's down to the source of the CSV to make sure they get it right. In 2011 this was more problematic.

Answer (score 65):

Let me throw out a few points in favor of CSV:

- CSV is simple(r than any alternative suggested in OP) to implement and parse
- CSV is understood by almost every piece of software on the planet (past and present)
- CSV forces a fairly flat, simple schema (there is a single flat list of fields)
- CSV is more human-readable than XML, JSON, or (UGH!) HL7 (V2.x, pre-xml)

Comment: You dont have to play 'devils advocate'... all those points you make are completely valid and explain why CSV is still used.  Its just plain simpler.

Comment: @GrandmasterB He's obviously frustrated, so I wanted to try to be non-confrontational in my answer. Instead of "you're wrong" it's "I'm not saying you're wrong, but let's look at the other side." The OP has some valid frustrations, even if they are somewhat misdirected. In any case, several others seem to agree that this isn't the best choice of wording, so I'll edit...

Comment: CSV is simple, but the data is not, and CSV parsers are often implemented badly. CSV has many variations. CSV is not readable after your with more than a dozen columns.

Comment: @Stephen: How many different variations of CSV do you know?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner how many escaping conventions can you think of?

Comment: @Stephen: Good answer.  I've written more than enough CSV handling code to know that not only are there multiple forms of CSV, but applications can be inconsistent with itself.  Notably some years ago I had to debug an Excel problem that turned out to be that Excel encoded returns differently and incompatibly when you were writing to a file versus cutting and pasting in another application!

Comment: @Pierre 303 I wish it was idiot proof. I'd be happy if it was developer proof.

Comment: It, Is, Simple, With, Little, Logic, Or, Assumptions, Built, Into, The, Data, Format, How, The, Data, Is, Interpreted, Is, Left, To, The, Reader, To, Decide,

Comment: @Pierre It's definitely not idiot write proof.

Comment: Stephen: from a user point of view, CSV is idiot proof, JSON is not. That's why CSV is always asked.

Comment: @Pierre303, idiot proof... If you think you've 'idiot proofed' something, you haven't tested it with enough idiots.

Comment: @Slomojo: just to clarify that "idiot" in that concept is just a term to give important to the whole expression, just like KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid).

Comment: @Pierre303, sigh - idiots, unlike the Tooth Fairy, are very real, and at some point all of us are the aforementioned idiot.

Comment: @Pierre - Best line I've read in a long time. I'm saving that one as a quote.

Comment: let's add another point to your list: CSV incurrs a lot less overhead than XML or other fancy formats, both in generation and parsing time and in network traffic. It's thus likely both faster and cheaper to employ.

Comment: *"CSV is understood by almost every piece of software on the planet"*. That's wrong, actually. If you save a CSV file with Excel, then I probably can't open it with Excel. The digit separator, field separator characters, number/date formats are all culture specific. So, e.g. if you save a CSV file with a German culture locale, the fields mus be separated by semicolons, not commas.

Answer (score 29):

Backwards compatibility. If your external orgs web service handles CSV, and all your existing tools handle CSV, neither party has any motivation to move to a new service. Why would your external org start supporting a different format? No-one they work with can use it! Why would you start producing a different format? None of the organizations you work with accept it!

The *real* issue I see here is, *why are your developers rolling their own CSV code every time?* If they used a stable, rock-solid CSV library, they wouldn't have the issues you describe. The problems are caused by developers rolling their own solution instead of using a library, and I honestly don't see how moving to JSON or XML magically fixes that. You'd still have people trying to regex them up instead of using a library.

Comment: +1 for rolling-their-own every time. I see developers who don't learn, not a flawed data format. :-)

Comment: 'backwards compatibility' - you are right of course -  but not moving forward is costing thousands.

Comment: Its fine to roll your own CSV library... just *re-use* it!

Comment: @Stephen: No, reimplementing CSV every time you need it is costing thousands. CSV as a format is fine, the developers who can't get it right are the problem.

Comment: 'rolling their own', right again, but switching to JSON on XML makes using a library easier, and'rolling your own' harder. (and I bet at least some of the culprits couldn't write a parser.)

Comment: @Stephen Costing thousands of what? Key-value storage like JSON is really only appropriate for semi-structured (schema-less) data. Fully structured data is best stored in a table.

Comment: @Anon: my point exactly.

Comment: @Stephen: So your problem with CSV is that it's too simple and you want something more complex?

Comment: @Anon.: My understanding from that point was that the storage methodology needs to be sufficiently complex that the hopeless devs don't attempt to code their own solution.  So in other words, protecting the system by making it too complicated for it's developers to interfere with.  I think firing is the answer here.

Comment: @chrisaycock thousands of pounds.  This data **is** stored in tables.

Answer (score 15):

CSV is a bit **faster**, **smaller in size**, very **easy** to handle (even in Excel) and many existing applications understand it, it is a widely used **standard**.

It is still a first choice in many situations.

I personally still like that format a lot. But I use JSON too, but for other applications like web UI.

Comment: I agree with every bit of this, except the initial use of "a bit".

Comment: It can be an absolute bas***rd with Excel if you have data that needs to retain leading zeros.... ask me how I know! ... other than that Excel provides a good interface.

Comment: @Dal: I used to work at a credit union, and had to deal with CSV files that contained credit card numbers.  Which have 16 digits.  That Excel rounded to 15.

Comment: Or worse that it converted them to scientific notation. :( I remember the first time I got an error back on our ACH processing that a remote account number was invalid, only to find out someone had edited the csv in excel (only to remove a row) and it had changed a bunch of 30 digit account numbers into 2.3456356e29 and such.

Comment: Oh, yes, scientific notation.  I've gotten some interesting results with alphanumeric customer IDs that happened to contain `E`s.

Comment: Those problems are not due to CSV, but to there being no way to tell Excel that a whole sheet should have a certain format (such as text) and should STAY that way.

Comment: @Jeanne: If CSV actually had a number/string distinction like JSON does, it would be quite easy to tell Excel which type the values are.  These problems are very much due to CSV being stringly typed.

Answer (score 15):

First and foremost, because even though *consuming* CSV data can be (slightly) non-trivial, generating it is *extremely* easy.

I'd also point out that neither JSON nor XML is really easier to get right (for either the producer or the consumer). In fact, one barely has to look around at all to know that *lots* of people try to use regexes to parse XML data, even though there's absolutely no question that doing so cannot and will not work.

Most of the problems that can (and do) arise with CSV can (and do) also arise with both JSON and XML. XML, in particular, adds many more potential problems of its own. A library to parse XML data is generally larger, slower, and more difficult to use than a similar library for CSV data.

Comment: *appearing* to produce it correctly is extremely easy, consuming something that lacks a spec is non-trivial when you have non-trivial data.

Comment: @Stephen: note that I did *not* include "correctly" in that first sentence. Its omission was intentional!

Answer (score 5):

First, I agree that there are some very real problems with the format:

- It's stringly typed.

  - With no distinction between text and numeric values, Excel will guess wrong and screw up your postal codes and credit card numbers.
  - There's no standard way to represent binary data.
  - There's no standard way to distinguish between `NULL` and `''`, which is a problem when importing CSV files into SQL databases.
- Poor support for "special characters".

  - The lack of numeric character references like (XML `&#xNNNN;` or JSON `\uNNNN`) means there is no standard way to represent control characters or non-ASCII characters.
  - Many implementations do not properly implement line breaks within a field.
- The lack of a standard.  There's [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), but it's not universally followed.

But on the other hand:

- The alternatives are worse.  JSON and XML, being designed around trees, are a poor fit for table-based data, specifically in terms of...
- **COMPACTNESS!**  In XML, you have to have a start tag and and end tag for *each* column in *each* row.  In CSV, you only write the column headers once.
- CSV is very easy to generate.
- Non-programmers can open CSV files in Excel.

Comment: in reverse; using this data in excel would be a sackable offence, CSV is easy to generate badly, compactness is not a problem, trees are a better fit for this data.

Answer (score 4):

Because a lot of analysts use Excel (for pivot tables and such), and it's a lot easier to output CSV than to output native Excel format.

Footnote: given how many problems I've seen with Excel handling CSV files, like removing leading zeroes and losing precision, this is probably a false sense of being easier.

Comment: This +1000. Excel is the killer application (once you know it) for quick and dirty analysis of data. Being able to export to Excel gives mighty powers to non-developers in business, research, etc.  Excel runs the world. CSV exports run Excel.

Answer (score 2):

If there is one thing wrong with CSV, it is that CSV appears so simple that many developer try to invent their own parsers/writers and later on blame CSV for not handling escaping correctly. With a good CSV parser (many good one out there), there will be no problem at all.

Some one mentioned CSV is not good for non-trivial data but I don't agree. XML allows non-trivial data because different data set can be put in different "container" tags. With CSV, you can always put different data in different files to achieve the same effect.

Further, in my opinion, using XML for data transfer fundamentally goes against the purpose of XML - data transfer usually implies a stable contract between providers and consumers while XML is meant to carry expandable information subject to interpretation when it is consumed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess CSV are just good when you only have simple text data, with only commas and either semicolon/endline at the end.

Tree architectured data or composited data can hardly be used with CSV.

CSV is just a plain 2D array of text as in excel, nothing much...

Answer (score 1):

It really is all about mainframes and excel here.

Mainframes because those old systems figured out how to communicate using CSV. So the big apps that dump the data can read and write it and have no reason to change now.

Excel because it can open CSVs directly. In fact, it takes over the .csv extension when you install it. Users just click the slightly funny looking excel icon and it opens and makes a nice grid they can wrangle with.

Now, modern versions of excel are quite capable of reading, say, XML, directly. But to do so, a user has to understand a bit more that "double click on that picture." And double clicking on the right picture can be too much to ask in some industries . . .

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a lot of technical answers but  I suspect the reason people use CSV is the same reason people use a lot of other techniques/technologies: **because it's the one they're the most familiar with**

Answer (score -1):

why do I use it?

1. the customer wants it
2. it's faster than xml over the network (smaller network load)
3. nothing more complex is needed to get the data across
4. cross platform
5. human readable
6. easy to implement readers and writers for it

etc. etc.